# htaccess: 301 Redirect all within a directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-search-console

In my previous application, I have a bunch of profiles located at: `http://www.example.com/profile/12312534`

But my new application no longer has those profiles. Is there a `301 Redirect` rule that can take care of every request that looks like `http://www.example.com/profile/*`?

Webmaster Tools currently shows me thousands of 404s that I'd like to remedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^profile/.*$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

This will redirect every `/profile/*` request to your home path `/` with R=301 (permanent redirect) thus taking care of your SEO ranking.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

**UPDATE:** Using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/profile/ /
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can do this as a `Redirect 301` rule in one line?

Comment: @dcolumbus: Edited answer as per your comment. However `RewriteRule` is also only liner. There are advantages of using `RewriteRule` like it is ignore case so `/profile` and `/PROFILE` will both be handled by `RewriteRule` but not with `RedirectMatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/profile/ /
```